# Problem with parsing xml from a string in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I want to parse an XML from a string. This is working fine when the string length is small. But for a long string it is not parsing anything. It is suspended on calling parse(). I use the following code for parsing. Please tell me what is the wrong with my code?

```
        //my xml code is string 'xmlString'
         DocumentBuilderFactory objDocFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder objDocBuilder=objDocFactory.newDocumentBuilder();  
         InputSource objInput=new InputSource();
         objInput.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlString));
         Document objDoc=objDocBuilder.parse(objInput);
         //appication is suspended at the above line
         objDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Thank you...

Comment: If you're parsing a large XML document, then you may want to use the SAX parser.

Answer (score 2):

How large is the document?

I have used TinyXML parser for Android, and am pretty satisfied with the result. Maybe you can check it out once.

Best part is it is pretty ease to use, and the learning curve is considerably less.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what Keith said.  Using DOM it's trying to load the entire document into memory, which is not the best thing on a mobile device.  SAX will stream the data so it will only use a little memory.